# Android Project not run resource style not found

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I have deleted .gradle and .idea folder to resolve the below issue then restart Android Studio but still it shows the below error.

ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar (aka com.paycall:style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar) not found.

```
Please find attached a screenshot from the below link.
```

[1]  [[https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ula6D.png]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ula6D.png)

Comment: I assume that you missed appcompat dependency, add it to app level gradle `implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'`

Comment: @rahat appcompat dependency already there. Please suggest another solution.